# Back up takes for ever 18.04LTS

Tags: 18.04

Have been trying to back up and it never appears to complete the job.
Keep asking for password verification.

Comment: Backup can mean different things for different people, system settings, applications or data.  For me backup generally means user data.  I use Timeshift for regular system settings backup, but for data - why not just copy the relevant folders, partitions, simple, easily managed.  If you wish to get a more meaningful answer here, I suggest you state which application you are using, a more detailed description, what you are trying to backup and the actual error message or screen print - good luck.